# Dependent Dropdown in Google Sheets Without Named Ranges, When the First Dropdown has Multiple of the Same Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

I have a dropdown selection of scene numbers in column A that contains selections from column H. When I select a scene number, I would like the next cell labeled "DESCRIPTION" to be a dropdown with the values from column I that match the scene number selected.

If I select "13" for scene number, I want the drop down options under "DESCRIPTION" to be "band", and "party crowd" for me to select. If I select "4" for scene number, I want the dropdown options in the next cell under "DESCRIPTION" to be "thugs". I tried to do a named range and other typical dependent dropdown options but nothing has worked.

Comment: Hi and welcome. First things first, do you know how to create a dependant dropdown? If you do, then I'm not sure that I understand the problem. It doesn't matter if some values are found in more than one dependant dropdown - you just define each of the unique dependant dropdowns and leave it to your script to select the appropriate dependant dropdown based on the parent selection.